# JavaScript associative array by variable

Tags: javascript, string, key, associative-array

I'd like to pass a variable into the key of my `monthHash` variable here:

```
 var monthHash = new Array();
  monthHash["JAN"] = "Jan";
  monthHash["FEB"] = "Feb";
  ...
  monthHash["NOV"] = "Nov";
  monthHash["DEV"] = "Dec";
```

Such that I can do this:

```
alert(monthHash[the_variable]);
```

Instead of using a switch case to go through this.

When I try, however, I get an error. Is there a way I can have a variable indicate a string identifier for the key in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only case that I can see where your code can generate an error is when `the_variable` is undefined (where you would receive a `ReferenceError`).

However, `Array` is not meant to be used for key/value pairs. You should use an object instead:

```
var monthHash = {};
monthHash['JAN'] = 'Jan';
monthHash['FEB'] = 'Feb';
monthHash['NOV'] = 'Nov';
monthHash['DEC'] = 'Dec';

var the_variable = 'NOV';

alert(monthHash[the_variable]);  // alerts 'Nov'
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it to be an object:

```
var monthHash = {};
monthHash["JAN"] = ..;
```

or

```
var monthHash = {jan: "...", ...}

var x = "jan";
alert(monthHash[x]);
```

Comment: Right - see a lot of literature (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) on why js arrays are not associative arrays, but use an Object instead.  (But I'd use "var monthHash = new Object();)